# Generate alert when Facebook share successful without FB.ui

Tags: facebook, alert

I am using sharer file to share on Facebook. I want to get a response back. There is help
only for [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/?_fb_noscript=1).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to subscribe to the following event(s):

edge.create

comment.create

message.send

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/